# Remove stack field from Nuxt createError response

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I made server API for validate some data on Nuxt like this :

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const body = await readBody(event);

  const result = schema.safeParse(body);

  if (result.success === false) {
    const error = result.error;

    const customError = createError({
      statusCode: 412,
      statusMessage: `${error.errors[0].path} ${error.errors[0].message}`,
    });
    throw customError;
  }

  return { ok: true };
});
```

so when i have bad inputs the createError function get called and i get some return like this :

```
{
    "url": "/api/car/listings",
    "statusCode": 412,
    "statusMessage": "make Required",
    "message": "make Required",
    "stack": "<pre><span class=\"stack internal\">at createError (/H:/nuxt/cartrader/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:48:15)</span>\n<span class=\"stack\">at /H:/nuxt/cartrader/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:794:25</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at async Object.handler (/H:/nuxt/cartrader/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:723:19)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at async Server.toNodeHandle (/H:/nuxt/cartrader/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:798:7)</span></pre>"
}
```

the question is how can I remove that stack field in the error response because it is a bit annoying to have that in JSON response especially if you want share that api with others? I tried to remove it like this :

```
const customError = createError({
      statusCode: 412,
      statusMessage: `${error.errors[0].path} ${error.errors[0].message}`,
    });
    delete customError.stack;
    throw customError;
```

but it only remove content inside stack field and the field it self still exist

```
{
    "url": "/api/car/listings",
    "statusCode": 412,
    "statusMessage": "make Required",
    "message": "make Required",
    "stack": "<pre></pre>"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did some research on this. apparently it only includes the stack field [if the server is in dev mode](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/53f7c1dfaad369df2be36884828e485fb5b065dc/packages/nuxt/src/core/runtime/nitro/error.ts#L19-L21). so this won't be appended in production.

if it does bother you in development, the cleanest 'fix' (which is essentially the same as `delete`), you can do this:

```js
throw createError({
  statusCode: 412,
  statusMessage: `${error.errors[0].path} ${error.errors[0].message}`,
  stack: undefined,
});
```